# Comparing a substring of a string

Tags: string, bash, substring

How can I check for a substring 0 in a string on first position in a bash shell?
In the code below, it says that the command is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
Stdalt=$(date +"%H")
if ["${Stdalt:0:1}" -eq "0"]
then
...
fi
```

Comment: Always consult https://www.shellcheck.net/ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The == comparison operator behaves differently within a double-brackets

```
[[ $Stdalt == 0* ]]   # True if $Stdalt starts with Stdalt "0" (wildcard matching).
[[ $Stdalt == "0" ]] # True if $Stdalt is equal to 0* (literal matching).
```

here what you are looking for :

```
#!/bin/bash
Stdalt=$(date +"%H")
if [[ $Stdalt == 0* ]]
then
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

also, You can select just the part of the string you want to check:

```
if [[ "${Stdalt:0:1}" = "0" ]]
then
.
.
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just found out that it works out well also with [ "${Stdalt:0:1}" == "0" ] Where is the difference between single and double brackets?

Comment: @X3nion then you can accept the answer, If you're referring to what happens when you echo something, the single quotes will literally echo what you have between them, while the double quotes will evaluate variables between them and output the value of the variable.